# Как читать поля при событии?

Tags: java, sql

У меня возникла проблема с передачей `JTextField` в другой класс. Есть класс `RegisterFrame` с `JTextField (userField, passwordField)` и кнопкой `enterButton`.

Введенные значения в `userField`, `passwordField` должны передаваться в класс `AppDirectoryMainFrame` и присваиваться значениям `user`, `passwd` в строке:

```
DataBaseTableModel dbtm = new DataBaseTableModel("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", user, passwd);
```

Код класса **RegisterFrame:**

```
userLabel = new JLabel("Пользователь");
userField = new JTextField();
passwordLabel = new JLabel("Пароль");
passwordField = new JPasswordField();
enterButton = new JButton("Вход");
enterButton.setToolTipText("Вход");
enterButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         AppDirectoryMainFrame frame = new AppDirectoryMainFrame();
         frame.setVisible(true);
         userField.setText(null);
         passwordField.setText(null);
         dispose();
     }
});
public String getUser(){
  return userField.getText();
}

public String getPasswd(){
  return passwordField.getText();
}
```

Код класса **AppDirectoryMainFrame:**

```
RegisterFrame frame = new RegisterFrame();
String user = frame.getUser();
String passwd = frame.getPasswd();
public final DataBaseTableModel dbtm = new DataBaseTableModel( "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", user, passwd);
```

Выдает ошибку:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

есть подозрения того что поля user и passwd не успевают записаться по тому что я создаю класс и сразу получаю юзер и пасворд. Читать эти поля нужно при событии. Я так понимаю при событии нажатия на кнопку enterButton. Но что бы я не делал ничего у меня не получается, подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы обращаетесь к разным экземплярам класса `RegisterFrame` и соответственно получаете не то что хотите. Вам надо при создании `AppDirectoryMainFrame`, передавать в конструкторе уже созданный ранее `RegisterFrame` и работать с ним, а не создавать его заново.

Что-то типа такого:

В конструкторе RegisterFrame:

```
final RegisterFrame frame = this;
enterButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         AppDirectoryMainFrame frame = new AppDirectoryMainFrame(frame);
         ...
     }
});
```

В AppDirectoryMainFrame:

```
public class AppDirectoryMainFrame extends RegisterFrame {

    public final DataBaseTableModel dbtm;

    public AppDirectoryMainFrame(RegisterFrame frame) {    
        String user = frame.getUser();
        String passwd = frame.getPasswd();
        dbtm = new DataBaseTableModel( "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", user, passwd);    
    }
}
```

Comment: что то типа такого?

`public class AppDirectoryMainFrame extends RegisterFrame {`

`public AppDirectoryMainFrame(RegisterFrame userField, RegisterFrame passwordField){
user = this.userField.getText();
passwd = this.passwordField.getText();`

Comment: @СашаСеменец нет, я сейчас обновлю ответ.

Comment: а как поступить тогда в месте с кнопкой?
`enterButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         AppDirectoryMainFrame frame = new AppDirectoryMainFrame();
         frame.setVisible(true);
         userField.setText(null);
         passwordField.setText(null);
         dispose();
     }
});`

Comment: подсвечивает ошибку в строке:
`AppDirectoryMainFrame frame = new AppDirectoryMainFrame(); frame.setVisible(true);`

Comment: @СашаСеменец обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое)
Все заработало)

Comment: А вы не считаете что лучше использовать инкапсуляцию, потому что в моем случае `RegisterFrame` вылазит поверх `AppDirectoryMainFrame`

Comment: А нет!
я подправил ваш код вот так: `public class AppDirectoryMainFrame extends JFrame {` и окна перестали накладываться

Comment: @СашаСеменец ну я наследование брал из вашего примера, так что наверное вам виднее как правильно его организовать.